# Room Retrofit Dagger2 MVP: Error: cannot find symbol variable DaggerAppComponent

Tags: android, dependency-injection, retrofit, dagger-2, android-room

I am trying to build an app that is based on [todo-mvp-dagger] and retrofit. After creating the initial classes, modules, room db (first time using) and rebuilding the project, I am receiving an error: cannot find symbol variable DaggerAppComponent

Following [todo-mvp-dagger](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture) app from Google Android Architecture sample.
The [todo-mvp-dagger] app is building fine but mine is not. 
What am I missing?
Here is my [project repository](https://github.com/abhi007tyagi/MVP-Dagger2-Retrofit-Room).

[image]

**Code is minimized now**

**UPDATE**
I updated the Dagger version and now I am getting following errors

1. `error: cannot find symbol variable DaggerAppComponent`
2. `/Users/abhinavtyagi/Documents/workspace/workspace_android/Research/UdacityCourseViewer/app/build/generated/source/apt/debug/com/tyagiabhinav/udacitycourseviewer/di/DaggerApplicationComponent.java:
   uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
   Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.`

/Users/abhinavtyagi/Documents/workspace/workspace_android/Research/UdacityCourseViewer/app/build/generated/source/apt/debug/com/tyagiabhinav/udacitycourseviewer/di/DaggerApplicationComponent.java:
uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

Comment: Show full error log from logcat

Comment: added, please check

Comment: Add error log about DaggerAppComponent

Comment: nothing more from Dagger, only - cannot find symbol variable DaggerAppComponent

Comment: Is it possible to import it?

Comment: I have shared my repo in the description. You can check the complete code.

Comment: my repo link - https://github.com/abhi007tyagi/MVP-Dagger2-Retrofit-Room

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174536/discussion-between-abhinav-tyagi-and-shmakova).

Comment: `pojo` package is not checked in

Comment: All code added back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace `DaggerAppComponent` with `DaggerApplicationComponent` since your component name is `ApplicationComponent` not `AppComponent`

Comment: I did that. Still the same